# Java sockets: newlines in packets as "one packet"

Tags: java, sockets, packet

Currently for my game my packets are like this:

[packet name]

[parameter]

[parameter]

As you can see I use newlines. Now the problem is java reads every packet with .readLine(), so only the packet name will be processed. Is there any way to make all these newlines into 1 packet?

Thanks

Comment: _java reads every packet with .readLine()_ Explain that by showing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no control over what you receive as a "packet" or a single read.  The minimum size is 1 unless you have non-blocking IO in which case it is 0.

What you can do is read the data and accumulate it so it can be processed in any manner you need.  I suggest you read each line until you have determined you have read the whole "packet" and then call a method to process it.

Comment: thanks for your response Peter!
I tried earlier what you said about making a method to process it, but the problem I can't detect the end of an packet. "while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)" I tried putting every fromServer string into another string and THEN process it out of the while loop, but the while loop never ends... Now I was thinking about upon sending a packet, encoding it in base64 so Java can't see there is a newline? Is that a good idea?

Comment: @Raoul The loop ends when the connection is closed.  If you want it to stop earlier you need another way to determine when a packet finishes. e.g. a blank line.  If you don't know a way to tell if a packet has ended there is no way for a program to magically work it out. The program is only as smart as you are even in an ideal world.  BTW The email SMTP takes a line with a `.` on a line by itself as the end of your mail message.

Comment: what do you think about the base64 idea?

Comment: @Raoul Base 64 is fine but I imagine it will complicate your solution and I don't see how it will help you.

Comment: well it could mask the newline so Java would think it is a full packet...Don't know if this is a good solution.

Comment: @Raoul You still need some way to know you have an end of packet to know when to stop reading base 64.  I would have a blank line or a `\0` on a line by itself. Much simpler.

Comment: Yeah I figured you are right! I ended up ending every packet with a "." Thank you so much!